# What happens when a browser's cache is full?

Tags: browser, browser-cache

What happens when a web browser's cache is full?  Does it

- Delete the oldest items in the cache to make room?
- Stop caching entirely?

Is this behavior documented for the major browsers like IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari?

Comment: I can't seem to find anything relevant on Google. Nice question!

Comment: This is.. rather interesting.

Comment: Google claims ever browser use LRU to decide what to dump. Here: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html

Comment: @MouseFood that sounds like an answer. want to post it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the programming aspect of this question. Can you explain? Otherwise, it's off-topic. :) (And all major versions of the browsers discard the older items to make room. The entire purpose of a cache is to keep the most recently accessed information available for quick access again, whether it be a browser cache, a file cache, a disk cache, a weapons cache, or whatever. <g>)

Comment: @paleozogt: I didn't downvote. I upvoted along with Blender.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm developing a website that will cache large files and wanted to know the implications of caching. It may seem obvious that LRU is how a browser cache works (its what I expected), but if its not written down anywhere *how do we know* that is the algorithm?  If its *so obvious*, why does google's own article say `as far as we know, all browsers clear their caches according to a Least Recently Used algorithm; we are not aware of any browsers that wait until resources expire before purging them`.  It wasn't clear to me, so I asked a question.

Comment: LRU indicates that it's the  oldest (least recently used) that are discarded. However, I still can't see a programming aspect; if you're developing a website, cache use in a web browswer isn't a concern to you, and there's absolutely no programming aspect to your question.

Comment: @KenWhite It's the community's call.  I think an algorithm question that has bearing on server-side behavior has a "programming aspect".  I'll note that, also in google's article, its defending the use of aggressive caching against a worry that it will "pollute" the client's cache (hence the note about LRU), which is exactly the FUD I'm trying to counter at work.

Comment: This is not an algorithm question, it's a generic "what does a browser do" question. However, you're right. It is the community's call - I gave you an opportunity to clarify somehow that it was on-topic before downvoting it. Sorry.

Comment: @KenWhite It looks like many of the questions in the browser-cache tag are similar to mine ("what does the browser do").  I guess I just had the misfortune of being noticed today.

Comment: Removed my downvote (due to your last comment). Still voting to close, though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google claims every browser use LRU to decide what to dump.

Here: [code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html)

Comment: So are there any tests that justify this claim?