# What will happen if i store cache and cache limit has been reached?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, browser-cache

I understand [each browser has a caching limit](http://www.blaze.io/mobile/understanding-mobile-cache-sizes/). Now I wonder what will happen if I try to store a cache when the limit has reached?

Will it delete older caches or just won't allow me to store it?

Aand if it does delete older caches, will they be mine or others? ( I don't mean the same page cache but caches by my website).

In general how does it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens when a browser's cache is full?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362292/what-happens-when-a-browsers-cache-is-full)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the cache that is used. Different caches are using different strategies:

- [FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)
- [LFU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_frequently_used)
- ...

In general it is difficult to find the right strategy for your cache since every strategy has its drawbacks.

Comment: But dosen't the browser "chooses" which strategy to use?

Comment: It most certainly does. But then again, do all browsers choose the same strategy?

Comment: Then can u expand on which used what?